# Entity Framework LINQ Query using Custom C# Class Method - Once yes, once no - because executing on the client or in SQL?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have two Entity Framework 4 Linq queries I wrote that make use of a custom class method, one works and one does not:

The custom method is:

```
public static DateTime GetLastReadToDate(string fbaUsername, Discussion discussion)
{
 return (discussion.DiscussionUserReads.Where(dur => dur.User.aspnet_User.UserName == fbaUsername).FirstOrDefault() ?? new DiscussionUserRead { ReadToDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-99) }).ReadToDate;
}
```

The linq query that works calls a from after a from, the equivalent of SelectMany():

```
  from g in oc.Users.Where(u => u.aspnet_User.UserName == fbaUsername).First().Groups
  from d in g.Discussions
  select new
  {
   UnReadPostCount = d.Posts.Where(p => p.CreatedDate > DiscussionRepository.GetLastReadToDate(fbaUsername, p.Discussion)).Count()
  };
```

The query that does not work is more like a regular select:

```
  from d in oc.Discussions
  where d.Group.Name == "Student"
  select new 
  {
   UnReadPostCount = d.Posts.Where(p => p.CreatedDate > DiscussionRepository.GetLastReadToDate(fbaUsername, p.Discussion)).Count(),
  };
```

The error I get is:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime GetLastReadToDate(System.String, Discussion)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

My question is, why am I able to use my custom GetLastReadToDate() method in the first query and not the second? I suppose this has something to do with what gets executed on the db server and what gets executed on the client? These queries seem to use the GetLastReadToDate() method so similarly though, I'm wondering why would work for the first and not the second, and most importantly if there's a way to factor common query syntax like what's in the GetLastReadToDate() method into a separate location to be reused in several different other LINQ queries.

Please note all these queries are sharing the same object context.

Comment: You cannot call custom methods in queries that execute on the DB. You can only use them in queries whose objects are already in memory.

Comment: So the reason the first query works is because after the first from statement everything else is executed in memory? Is there any way to encapsulate LINQ query segments to be used in several different consuming queries even when those queries are executed on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your better of using a **[Model Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx)** here.

Define a scalar function in your database which returns a **DateTime**, pass through whatever you need, map it on your model, then use it in your LINQ query:

```
from g in oc.Users.Where(u => u.aspnet_User.UserName == fbaUsername).First().Groups
  from d in g.Discussions
  select new
  {
   UnReadPostCount = d.Posts.Where(p => p.CreatedDate > myFunkyModelFunction(fbaUsername, p.Discussion)).Count()
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

> > and most importantly if there's a way to factor common query syntax like what's in the GetLastReadToDate() method into a separate location to be reused in several different places LINQ queries.

A stored procedure would probably be one way to store that 'common query syntax"...EF, at least 4.0, works very nicely with SP's.